# Powershell match export-csv with format shown in Windows Powershell ISE

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a script that exports evens from the eventlog like:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Where-Object Source -Match "my application"  | export-csv "$FileDate.csv"
```

When I open the CSV it does not look how I want it too. It shows

> EventID,"MachineName","Data","Index","Category","CategoryNumber","EntryType","Message","Source","ReplacementStrings","InstanceId","TimeGenerated","TimeWritten","UserName","Site","Container"
> 0,"DESKTOP-ID94AN3","System.Byte[]","21425","(0)","0","Error","Finished
> executing project 'Testproject' Execution Package 'Failure' Execution
> failed Start Time : 21/12/2020 19:47:52 End Time : 21/12/2020 19:47:56
> on server: DESKTOP-ID94AN3
> -Logmessage

After text-to-columns:

[image]

With information in columns where it should not be.  It seems to combine the 2 windows from the event viewer. The 'upper' window with the errors and the 'lower' window with the details. All I want is the upper window.

If I run this code in Windows Powershell ISE:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Where-Object Source -Match "Myapplication"
```

It looks how I want it too look (after using text to columns):

```
   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   21425 Dec 21 19:47  Error       Myapplication LogEn...            0 Message 1                                                                                                                                                                 
   21424 Dec 21 19:47  Information Myapplicationr LogEn...            0 Message 2
```

How do I get my CSV export to look like this also?

Comment: what you show is NOT csv format ... it is the powershell display system showing the collection of objects that came from a CSV import. the actual file is just text divided by a delimiter character.

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: you say `It looks how I want it too look:` and show what powershell shows after you import a CSV ... **_but that is not a CSV - it is a powershell array created by importing the CSV._** ///// you CANNOT make a CSV that looks like that ... it would not be a CSV! [*grin*] it would only be a plain text file with almost zero structure.

Comment: Ok, to rephrase, that's how i want it to look after i use text-to-columns on my CSV. And it doesn't. Everything under 'Execution failed' (see screenshot) should not be in the same column as EventID.

Comment: kool! now, PLEASE change your Question to say what you actually want. it still refers to wanting a CSV file to look like a plain text report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it look the way you want by selecting only the specific columns you care about, before sending the results over to `Export-CSV`.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | Where-Object Source -Match "edgeupdate" | 
    Select -first 10 -Property Index, Time, EntryType, Source, InstanceId, Message | 
      Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Comment: That works, except for the Message. It seems to put it under the first column as seen in my screenshot.

Comment: @Elmer Try it with `-UseCulture` switch appended to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet. I have the feeling your Excel uses a different delimiter character than the default comma.

Comment: Does your application have a lot of comma characters in your Message field?  Maybe that's related

Comment: @Elmer did you double-click the file or imported into excel and then did `text-to-columns`? message is probably a multiline string. `text-to-columns` probably messes up when it sees newlines. Simply double-click, but do use `-UseCulture` otherwise excel puts it all into column 1

Comment: @Theo I simply double click the file to open it in excel then use text to columns.

Comment: @Elmer If you export using the delimiter character Excel expects (by adding `-UseCulture``) you don't need to perform Text-To_Columns. That is the part that messes up your Excel sheet.